# Can you create a custom driver for STB?

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm new to Android development, so I'm not sure if this can be done.

Google TV is great, but it only controls the STB through IR, which doesn't always work.  I was thinking about creating an app for the DirecTv STBs that Google TV can control through the STB's REST interface.

Does anyone think this is possible or does Google have to create such an animal?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create an app, but there isn't a mechanism to integrate that within a Google TV.  BTW - Google TV is 2-way paired with Dish boxes over Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping we could create a custom implementation of STB driver.  So in the area where you setup you TV, Audio, and STB, a developer could add another option to the STB list.  I also would like more types of devices in this list like DVD/BluRay player.